# How to get Client Certificate in Middleware ASP.Net Core 5?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-5, webapi

I have a middleware trying to receive Client Certificate from Postman Certificates it reads Null
In Program.cs I have allowed Certificates as well

```
 webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(o =>
 {
    o.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(o =>
    o.ClientCertificateMode = 
      ClientCertificateMode.AllowCertificate);
  });
```

below is my code Snippet

```
 public class ApiKeyMiddleware
 {
  public ApiKeyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
  {
    _next = next;
  }
  public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
  {
     var cert = context.Request.Connection; // Is NULL in headers as well
     await _next(context);
  } 
}
```

Comment: what kind of certificate are you using. it works if you have proper certificate

Comment: @CodingMytra Self Signed Certificate I am using.

Comment: and how did you generated this self signed certificate ? for me it works with a certificate signed by a proper CA but not with self signed certificate. so definitely no issues with your code.

Answer (score 0):

in IIS Express Certificates wont work, Change to project it runs in port 5001, works Fine, Hence Closing Thanks.